# Transforming Rank-Ordered Variable

Tags: regression, scales, ranking

I am currently working on an archival dataset (General Social Survey 1985). In a measure, participants are asked to rank 5 job characteristics by degree of preference. In other words, participants decide what characteristic is the most important, what is the second most important, and so on, in a hypothetical job.

I am particularly interested in how they ranked 2 of the 5 characteristics, because they match  very well with a construct I am studying. These 2 characteristics actually tap into both extremes of my construct. As an illustration, if my construct of interest was job autonomy, one of the characteristics would be "Making important decisions in my job" while the other one would be "being closely supervised."

In my model, the construct "autonomy" is the predictor of another construct in this dataset. The other construct is continuous.

If the data for characteristic preference was simple likert scales, things would be MUCH easier. I would probably try to combine the two items into a single score.

The problem is I do not know how to re-code / analyze this type of ranking for my two job characteristics. What I have done so far is calculate a difference score between "Making important decisions in my job" and "being closely supervised", which enables me to capture a relative preference for one or the other.

What would you suggest me to do?